# Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to get the user information of the user who left this review.

With the following code:

```
SELECT username, image, user_id FROM table_users AS us
JOIN table_reviews AS re
ON re.user_id = us.user_id
WHERE us.user_id = 1 AND
re.review_id= 1
```

I get the error:

> Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

What does this mean?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means that both tables in the query have the column `user_id`.

You need to specify which one you want to get in the SELECT statement like 
`SELECT username, image, re.user_id`

Answer (score 6):

column user_id is in both `table_reviews`, `table_users`  tables.

You need to specify columns with table alias name also.

```
SELECT username, image, us.user_id FROM table_users AS us
JOIN table_reviews AS re
ON re.user_id = us.user_id
WHERE us.user_id = 1 AND
re.review_id= 1
```

Answer (score 5):

It means column user_id is in both tables ie, in `table_reviews, table_users`

Try like this:

```
SELECT username, image, us.user_id    //or re.user_id
FROM table_users AS us
JOIN table_reviews AS re
ON re.user_id = us.user_id
WHERE us.user_id = 1 AND
re.review_id= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only selected values(SELECT username, image, user_id) are examined in where clause (WHERE us.user_id = 1), all joined columns are examined in where clause, so in your example you have user_id column in both joined tables. If you have query like this one:

```
SELECT table_reviews.id FROM table_users AS us
JOIN table_reviews AS re
ON re.user_id = us.user_id
WHERE id
```

id will be ambiguous because id-s from table_reviews and table_reviews  will be examined in where clause although only id from table_reviews is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `user_id` field exists in both tables. You need to specify which table's `user_id` you want.

```sql
SELECT username, image, re.user_id
```