# Django query get day from DateTimeField

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have some orders saved in database, I want to retrieve just the day from order, so I did this:

```
Order.objects.all().extra(select={'day':'day(date_added)'}).values('day').order_by('day')
```

But I get this error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1052, "Column 'date_added' in field list is ambiguous"), and my Order model has the field date_added.

My model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="orders")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: show your model in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is likely occurring because there is another field named `date_added` in that SQL: for example, a related table could have the same field.

You could try prepending the table name to the field:

`.extra(select={'day':'day(app_order.date_added)'})`

Assuming the table name is `app_order`.

See more on Django's extra method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra

In particular, look at the section on getting the Blog object count:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_entry WHERE blog_entry.blog_id = blog_blog.id`

Note the use of the tablename `blog_blog`.

For more reference:

The value in field list is ambiguous error: [Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068954/column-user-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous)